# Firebase list data returning multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase

```
var invitationsRef = new Firebase(FB + "/invites");

invitationsRef.on("child_added", function (snapshot){
   $('#invitations').append("<li>You are invited to" + snapshot.val().email + 
   "</li><button class='joinGroup' value='Join " + snapshot.val().group + 
   "'</button></li>");
```

The code above works in that it displays a list of invitations.  The problem I am having comes after, shown in the following code.

```
$(".joinGroup").on("click", function(){
    console.log(this.value);
}
```

So when I click one of the appended buttons it logs the value of the list item which is also what I wanted.  Problem is that it will log it multiple times.  The item at the bottom of the list will be logged once when clicked.  The next one up will be logged twice when clicked.  The pattern will continue until as I add more items to the list.  If there are 5 items in the list then it will log the top one 5 times from one button click.

Can anyone explain why this is happening and what the solution is?

Comment: It should log once per button unless you're binding to the event multiple times. Where are you binding to `click`?

Comment: That is pretty much all of my code regarding this list, so I am assuming from what you have said that I need to do some reading on binding to click events to solve this problem?

Comment: You might be binding more than once. Have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/v3hn4xhh/ `1st handler:` always logs once per click, so does '2nd handler:'. But `2nd-inner handler:` will keep increasing at each click. You might have something similar in your code.

Comment: Move `$(".joinGroup").on("click"` outside of the function it is in now.

Comment: Yes, that is what was happening and that solution fixed it.  Thanks!